# Ionic/Angular JS accordion: Can I show a template inside a line of the accordion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic and what I am trying to achieve is to present different non-static information into an accordion that shows or appear with a button. The thing is that each item it will be showing different information and I need to place images an more things.

Can I show a template inside each line or only plain text? How can I show more than only text?

Because the information is in the group array in the controller... so I have no idea how to do it.

I just take the example of the accordion from here...
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxJvxJ

**HTML...**

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Ionic Accordion</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Accordion List</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>

      <ion-list>
        <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
          <ion-item class="item-stable"
                    ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
                    ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
              <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
            &nbsp;
            {{group.title}}
          </ion-item>
          <div ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="content in group.contents" class="item-accordion">
              <a href="">{{content.line}}</a>
            </ion-item>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

  </body>
```

**CSS..**

```
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

/*
 * http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage_animations
 */
.list .item.item-accordion {
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.09s all linear;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0px;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-add,
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-remove {
  display: block !important;
}
```

**JS...**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
      title: "INTRODUCTION",
      contents: [
        {
          line: "DONT BE AFRAID"
        },
        {
            line: "WHY, WHAT & WHO"
        },
        {
                line: "PITCH OR PRESENT"
        },
        {
                line: "GREAT PRESENTATIONS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "PREPARATION",
      contents: [
        {
          line: "WHY?"
        },
        {
            line: "WHAT IS THE MESSAGE?"
        },
        {
                line: "WHAT IS THE VEHICLE?"
        },
        {
                line: "WHO ARE THE AUDIENCE?"
        }
      ]
    },
      {
      title: "PITCH STRUCTURE",
      contents: [
        {
          line: "BLAH"
        },
        {
            line: "BLAH"
        },
        {
                line: "BLAH"
        },
        {
                line: "BLAH"
        },
        {
                line: "BLAH"
        },
        {
                line: "BLAH"
        },
        {
                line: "BLAH"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  /*
   * if given group is the selected group, deselect it
   * else, select the given group
   */
  $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };

});
```

So if anyone can point me the correct path to follow now it would be great.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to define a _dynamic_ template instead of only a text `line` then you have to  escape it. See [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

`line : $sce.trustAs('<div>your template</div>);`

Comment: When you mean ('<div>your template</div>); I have to put my code in it or the name of the template?

Comment: Either you define your html code as above or you define a templateUrl and use the `ngInclude` directive to place the content. `<div ng-include="content.templateUrl"></div>`

Comment: I have an error while doing it:
Error: [$sce:icontext] Attempted to trust a value in invalid context. Context: <div>your template</div>; Value: undefined